# The way caching data in Twitter for iOS. NSUserDefaults? or SQLite?

Tags: objective-c, caching

I can see Twitter time line in no internet connection, Of course, cannot reload latest data.

This is because of cache data, I guess.

But, What approach was taken? NSUserDefaults? SQLite?

Please let me know good solution, or more effective approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea how Twitter app does it but for RESTful web services I recommend [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit). It can cache the requests for you using Core Data for persistence.